# Get variable of a factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-services

I have a problem. I am making an application AngularJS and when inject a factory in a controller gives me undefined.
The problem is when I call factory. I am not able to get the value of the response.

Factory:

```
 app.factory('mapFactory', function($http){
      return {
        getCoordinates: function() {
          return $http.get("http://xxxx/map.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK").then(function(response){
              return response.data;
              console.log(response.data); // "37.344/-4.3243"
          });
        }
      }
    });
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('MapCtrl', function(mapFactory) {
   var coordinates;
   mapFactory.getCoordinates().then(function(response){
     return coordinates = response;
   });
   console.log(coordinates); // undefined
   var elem = coordinates.split('/'); // Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
   latitude = elem[0];
   longitude = elem[1];
});
```

Comment: So, what is `undefined`? The factory, or the response from the factory?

Comment: why not `var coordinates = mapFactory.getCoordinates().then(function(response){
     return response;
   });` ?
Plus, we kinda need to know what's undefined, like @Tom said.   
Also, I'm not sure that that `return $http` is doing what you want.

Comment: Undefined is coordinates (Cannot read property 'split' of undefined). The factory works correctly. I think the problem is in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$http.get` call is asynchronous, so `coordinates = response` will be set when the get requerst finished, but the following code will be executed immediately. You could move the rest of the code into the `then` function to make it work

```
  app.controller('MapCtrl', function(mapFactory) {
   var coordinates;
   mapFactory.getCoordinates().then(function(response){
     return coordinates = response;
     console.log(coordinates); 
     var elem = coordinates.split('/'); 
     latitude = elem[0];
     longitude = elem[1];
   });
});
```